# Optimized MySQL data store

Tags: mysql, optimization, datastore

I would like to store user information in a table.

**First example**
The fields are eg. "has car", "has flat", "has cat", "has dog", "has LCD TV", "has notebook"...

The value of fields can be y/n or y/null (null means empty value in table).

The fields above are filled random, eg. 
"y", "null", "null", "null", "y", "null"
OR
"y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n"

So only those fields contain useful information for me which is filled in "y", because when I use query I just want to see the result of those fields, which contain only "y" value.

Is there any possibility for this because obviously each records' result will differ from the others?

**The second solution**
I create a table which stores the user id and the property of the user, eg.

user id    property
1          has car 
1          has dog
2          has LCD TV
3          has flat
3          has notebook
3          has cat

Here the unnecessary information are not stored but DB can have more than 100000 rows.

My question is what is the best store method. About 100-120 property will be used to one user. And there will be another table which will connect to the original table which also will contain further 50 similar property (y/null).

I think the second solution is best but I have doubt with speed. Of course primary key will be used and the more important fields (foreign key) will be received "Unique". (I heard with unique we can received the results more quickly.)

What do you think of writing above?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Best Regards&Nice Day,
Atti

Comment: How static is the list of "has" items?  That is, will there be a few new ones next week?  If so, ENUM, SET, INT, columns could be messy.  And that would lead to JSON and other options.

Comment: How many "users"?  If only 1000, performance will probably fine, no matter what way it is implemented.  If 1M, then it will probably be wise to find a way to store each "has" in one bit (even smaller than Y/null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, if I understand correctly, best solution here is to create many to many relationship between table **user** (which contain user_id and some info about user if it's required) and second table let's call it **has** which will contain has_id and name(there will be stored what user have dog, tv, cat, etc.).

To create many to many relationship you need third table, called a junction table, which can be named **user_had** and which contains pair of field **user_id** and **has_id** which will be primary key pair (that means that you won't be allowed to have two identical pair (user_id and has_id) in the table).

So when you want to pull out data from table let's say what user under user_id 5 have you will do that with something like this

```
SELECT user_has.user_id, user_has.has_id, has.name
FROM user_has INNER JOIN has
ON user_has.has_id = has.has_id
WHERE user_has.user_id = 5;
```

when you inserting you have to insert only user_id and has_id into user_has table which will make new pair... etc..

Answer (score 0):

Which is better depends on how the data will be queried and how ti might change in future. (TL;DR - the first solution sucks so much it blows).

Suppose you want to run a query to find out what users have a dog. To avoid looking at every row in the database you need an index - so that means you need to create an index for every field in the table.

Now consider what happens when you want to add a new "has". In order to make space for the new attribute, you need to re-write every row in the table (this is not strictly true as MySQL, like most DBs tends to add in a bit of spare space, but at some point this will be exhausted). Certainly your table will be unusuable for some time while you apply the new schema - you have to change the schema every time you add a new asset.

For a very small proportion of all the possible queries you could run on the two models, using separate columns for each asset will be faster, but for the vast majority, it will be no different or faster to use the user/key/value table. It will certainly be a lot faster to carry out an insert as you only need to update one or two indexes.