# multiple room in one booking mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to develop hotel booking system using php and mysql. There are 3 tables that I have created, Customer, Booking, Room. This are example for my table and their relationship.

```
 Booking(booking_id, room_id, customer_id, date_depart, date_arrived, price)

 Customer(customer_id, username, password, name, nophone)

 Room(room_id, room_type, status)
```

**Question :** Is it possible customer can make booking more than one booking?

And how to maintain the same booking id for many room booking?

Comment: Hi, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053821/optimized-mysql-data-store/29054432#29054432) is one my answer about many-to-many relationship look there and look a little about that online :) then comeback here if you have some problem with that..

Comment: Of course many to many relationship should be created between Booking and Room... and that is solution for your second question... And i don't see any problem why customer couldn't make more then one booking. It's should work just fine when table is created like this. Customer can make as many Bookings as he want.